# Sum mysql results into specified group

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT 
    f.hmis, sa.number_of_computers, sa.service_area
FROM
    facility_service_area sa,
    facility f
WHERE
    f.hmis = sa.facility_hmis


hmis   comp serv_area
80703   3   MCH
80706   1   LD
80701   2   ART
80701   3   ART
80701   2   LD
80701   3   LD
80701   2   MCH
80701   1   MCH
80702   4   MCH
80707   1   MCH
80707   4   MCH
```

**I would like to sum all computers where in each specified service area under each hmis where results look like this.**

```
hmis   comp. Service_area
80703   3   MCH
80706   1   LD
80701   5   ART
80701   5   LD
80701   3   MCH
80702   4   MCH
80707   4   MCH
```

Comment: sum of what of price or you mean group by ?!

Comment: Format your expected output. Not clear what to sum or group by?

Comment: notice that hmis 80701 has ART,LD and MCH fields, therefore i need to group by HMIS and service_ area where result will be like                80701   5   ART
80701   5   LD
80701   3   MCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use GROUP BY with SUM() aggregate function. 
SELECT f.hmis,
       SUM(sa.number_of_computers),
       sa.service_area
FROM facility_service_area sa,
     facility f
WHERE f.hmis = sa.facility_hmis
GROUP BY sa.service_area


Also you can use INNER JOIN for this.

SELECT f.hmis, SUM(sa.number_of_computers), sa.service_area
FROM facility_service_area sa INNER JOIN
facility f
ON f.hmis = sa.facility_hmis
GROUP BY sa.service_area
```

Comment: notice that hmis 80701 has ART,LD and MCH fields, therefore i need to group by HMIS and service_ area where result will be likd                80701   5   ART
80701   5   LD
80701   3   MCH

Answer (score 1):

First.  *Never* use comma in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You just want a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT f.hmis, sa.service_area, SUM(sa.number_of_computers)
FROM facility_service_area sa JOIN
    facility f
    ON f.hmis = sa.facility_hmis
GROUP BY f.hmis, sa.service_area;
```

In an aggregation query, I almost always put the aggregation columns first followed by the computed columns.  This helps prevent errors, because it is easy to check that the columns used for the aggregation match what is being returned.